# Jquery dialog close funcationality

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I am having a Jquery dialog with two buttons Add and Cancel. User will input few fields and on pressing Add button, I am doing UI modifications and validations. After all the operations are done, I am closing the dialog. But issue is, even though I am closing the dialog after save and other operations, but the dialog is getting closed before the operations gets completed.

Below is my Jquery dialog code,

```
    dlg.dialog({
        height:300,
        width:600,
        modal:true,
        autoOpen:true,
        title: "Add Property",
        closeOnEscape:true,
        buttons: {
            "Cancel": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            },
            "Create Property": function() {
                    //Validate Property 
                    // Save Property 
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        }
     }); 

    function save() {
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ServiceUrl,
        data: parameter,
        success : function(data) {

            // Convert the response text to JSON format
            var jsonData = eval('(' + data + ')');

            if (jsonData.results) {
                   // success
            } 
         }
      });
    };
```

In above code I am executing $(this).dialog("close"); after validate and save function but my dialog is getting closed , before these function finishes. This behavior doesn't happen if I execute line by line by keeping breakpoints in firebug. Please help in resolving and help me in understanding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There seems to be a extra `}` after `dialog("close")`..  just fyi.

Comment: Do validation and saving use ajax by any chance?

Comment: @Asad : yes they are ajax calls.

Comment: It appears that you need to do `$(this).dialog("close");` in the success callback of the `.ajax()` call.

Comment: @Senthil AJAX calls are async and so the below `dialog('close')` will be called right away..

Comment: Well then you need to call `$(this).dialog("close");` as part of the complete or success handler of the last one called, and they need to be chained. Please show your validate and save methods.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `.ajax()` call(s) are asynchronous, the `$(this).dialog("close");` does not wait for the `.ajax()` call to finish. Put the `dlg.dialog("close");` inside the success of the `.ajax()` call after you see that the save/validations were successful.

```
dlg.dialog({
    height:300,
    width:600,
    modal:true,
    autoOpen:true,
    title: "Add Property",
    closeOnEscape:true,
    buttons: {
        "Cancel": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Create Property": function() {
                //Validate Property 
                // Save Property 
                $.ajax({
                    success: function (response) {
                       //test to see if the response is successful...then
                       dlg.dialog("close");
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                       //code for error condition - not sure if $(this).dialog("close"); would be here.
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: There are actually two ajax calls, and the dialog needs to close after both have completed.

Comment: @Asad, if that is the case, then I would suggest not making two calls; validate and save with one call.

Comment: There are probably two different scripts that are being requested, which is why there are two different ajax calls.

Comment: @Asad, depending on what each call does server side, isn't there a potential security risk there?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic should look something like:

```
dlg.dialog({
    height:300,
    width:600,
    modal:true,
    autoOpen:true,
    title: "Add Property",
    closeOnEscape:true,
    buttons: {
        "Cancel": function() {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Create Property": function() {
                $.ajax({//Validate request
                    ...
                    success:function(response){
                        $.ajax({//Save request
                            ...
                            success:function(response){
                                //close the dialog here
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
 });
```

Either you can chain your ajax calls like this, or you can make them asynchronous by passing an `async:false` option.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the need for a global "save" function, as it eliminates the need to write the same script over and over again.

Try doing something like this:

```
dlg.dialog({
    height: 300,
    width: 600,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: true,
    title: "Add Property",
    closeOnEscape: true,
    buttons: {
        "Cancel": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Create Property": function () {

            save(true); //!!!

        }
    }
});
```

And then:

```
function save() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ServiceUrl,
        data: parameter,
        success: function (data) {
            // Convert the response text to JSON format
            var jsonData = eval('(' + data + ')');
            if (jsonData.results) {

                //!!!! Then close the dialog
                dlg.dialog("close") //!!!!

            }
        }
    });
}
```

This way, your close function is not called until the AJAX response is received.

---

**EDIT:** I would also set the `dlg` variable and the `save()` function-name as globals by attaching them to the `window` object like so:

```
window.dlg = $("#myDialogElement");
window.save = function () {
    //function stuff here 
}
```

This will ensure they're always available.